# To find the Critical Points of this Function

Tags: calculus

1.) $f(x) = \frac{6x}{x-1}$

My professor stated that the answer is $x = 1$ and I don't understand how that's the case. Can someone explain how the answer is $x = 1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your function is not defined at x=1. A critical point of a function is a point in its domain where the derivative is zero or undefined.

Comment: Not to forget the boundary points, if any.